# Centering table within fbox

Tags: tables, boxes

I want to center (a) the contents of the table and (b) the table itself within a fbox. I do not know how to do this within the fbox environment. Currently my code is the following:

```
\fbox{%
   \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
            {\centering
    \textbf{Box 3a: Example}\par
    }
     \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.}
     \bigskip
            \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}}
             \hline
             Group      &   Column      &   Column \\
             \hline
             A                  &   3               &   12                  \\           
             B                  &   5               &   14                  \\           
             \hline
            \end{tabular}
  }%
}
```

Leading to the following output. However, I would like both the contents of the column and the table itself to be centere within the box.

[image: Current situation]

Comment: just remove the `{` before `\centering` and the `}` after the bold heading, you have kept `\cemtering` away from the table by having that group.

Comment: (or add another `\centering` later, if you don't want the big text centred)

Comment: Please advise if the `\fbox` should also be centered horizontally. (Currently, that's not the case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the title you can, as in the MWE, use `\centering`. I would do it with `\hfill` instead. The table can be centered with the `center` environment, which will also add some space around it. Centering of the columns in the table can be done by loading the `array` package and defining a new column type, here `C`. Finally,. I would recommend to use `booktabs` for the lines in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
    \hfill\textbf{Box 3a: Example}\hfill\strut

    \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.}

    \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{C{2cm} C{2cm} C{2cm}}
        \toprule
        Group      &   Column      &   Column \\\midrule
        A                  &   3               &   12                  \\           
        B                  &   5               &   14                  \\           
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code:

```
\fbox{%
   \parbox{0.9\textwidth}{%
            {\centering
    \textbf{Box 3a: Example}\par
    }
     \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.}

\begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{l ll}
             \hline
             Group      &   Column      &   Column \\
             \hline
             A                  &   3               &   12                  \\           
             B                  &   5               &   14                  \\           
             \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{center}
  }%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to use the `framed` environment, which has the advantage to break across pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{framed}

\begin{document}

\begin{framed}
  \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\textbf{Box 3a: Example}}\medskip

  \noindent \textit{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.}

  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}}
    \hline
    Group & Column & Column \\
    \hline
    A & 3 & 12 \\
    B & 5 & 14 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{framed}%

\end{document}
```

[image]